# How to translate a field name for all resources in react-admin

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

The translation of generics inputs was the same for all resources, so how can i specifiy it in the resource file ?

something like this should be great !

```
export default {
    resources: {
        '*': {
            fields: {
                lastname: 'Nom',
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible for now but that looks like a good feature request. Would you mind opening an issue about it on our repository?